# Which pages affect text area CSS?

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

I have a text area with [CKEditor](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor). The default font in this text area and my theme is 20 pixels and I cannot change its size with CSS, but if I change theme and use Garland, the font change to the normal size.

If I copy Garland styles and page.tpl.php in my theme, the text area is still using a 20 pixels font. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CKEditor set its own CSS classes for text areas, but that would not explain why copying the CSS files from a theme to another doesn't change the visualized styles.

The problem here is that simply changing the files used by a theme doesn't change the used styles; you need to let Drupal know the theme has been changed, and this can be done in two ways:

- you select a different theme as default one, disable the theme you modified, re-enable it, and select it again as default theme
- you force Drupal to refresh the cache it is using, or you empty the cache tables

In the first case, you submit the theme selection form after each operations.

Comment: thank u for edit my question :) and your response.  i tried two resolution but it didnt work.

Comment: thank u. problem was with cache. and this code help me too .cke_show_borders {
background:white;
font-size:12px;
}